# INSERT INTO SELECT STATEMENT with multiple FK

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, foreign-keys

This is my code with 1 `FK`.
here's the columns

```
([PK]charityRoomID, charityRoomStatus, [FK]charityWardID)
```

---

```
INSERT INTO tbl_addcharityroom1 (charityRoomStatus, charityWardID) 
VALUES ('"+jTextField10aw.getText() +"', (
    select charityWardID 
    from tbl_addcharityward 
    where diseaseCategory='"+ jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString() +"'))";
```

Now, I added a new column(`RateID`) which is another `FK`, but i don't know the correct statement for multiple `FK`. here's the columns

```
([PK]charityWardID, charityRoomStatus, [FK]charityWardID, [FK]rateID)
```

I am using netbeans & mySQL

Answer (score 0):

A FK is just a constraint on a database column. It basically means that your column content must map to a specified column when you insert data.

So, if your insert statement specifies a value that exist in the ID column of your Rate table, everything will be allright. Otherwise, an exception will occur.

Basically you just need to do this, replacing "yourRateIdValue" by an Id that actually exist in your Rate table:

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_addcharityroom1 (charityRoomStatus, charityWardID, rateID) 
VALUES ('" + jTextField10aw.getText() + "', (
    select charityWardID 
    from tbl_addcharityward 
    where diseaseCategory='"+ jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString() +"'), yourRateIdValue)";
```

You can also replace the "yourRateIdValue" by a select statement, as you did for the "charityWardID" column